# Efficient construction of a dodecahedron

Tags: general-topology, geometry, platonic-solids

This is essentially a manufacturing question: Is it possible to build a dodecahedron using 12 pentagonal panels that are all identical and can be joined mechanically? I am trying to come up with a solution that does not require separate parts.

Comment: See [this picture](https://www.flickr.com/photos/karlhorton/411197010) of a dodecahedron made from [polydrons](http://www.polydron.co.uk/)

Comment: @Jim Belk: Nice picture which is showing a practically manufactured dodecahedron. But do you know each two pentagonal faces are inclined at an equal angle $\approx 116.56^o$ with each other at their common edge?

Comment: Are you questioning whether all of the faces are congruent regular pentagons, @HarishChandraRajpoot? Because if you believe they are, there's no freedom to the dihedral angle.

Comment: The nice thing about hinged joints is you do not have to painstakingly construct them to the angle $116.56^\circ$; they will automatically adjust to that angle when you attach the third pentagonal face to the other two faces meeting at a vertex.

Comment: @ David K: Initially you have to first join two pentagons mechanically at their common edge  at the angle $\approx 116.56^o$. In order to automatically adjust the pentagons, you have to join five pentagons simultaneously at all five edges of a sixth pentagon which seems it needs slight tagging at all common edges in welding operation to hold them mechanically.

Comment: @ Benjamin James: There should be exact details about the type of joints of pentagonal panels (faces) at all 30 edges i.e. either hinge joints or weld joints because a manufacturing process depends on the joining operations to be used for required precision.

Comment: As mentioned in the first sentence that this  is essentially a manufacturing question then it should have details about type of joints to be used to mechanically join all pentagonal panels to build a dodecahedron.

Comment: I provided the value of diahedral angle $\approx 116.56^o$ between any two adjacent pentagons is of great importance in manufacturing operation being used to build a dodecahedron because it helps to compare the actual value of dihedral angle with the theoretical value to measure angular deformation at the edges caused in the process for obtaining the precision.

Comment: @DavidK - Hinged/complementary joints are what I had in mind. Something similar to the picture that Jim posted, but rather than ALL edges being identical, I am looking for an arrangement that utilizes 2 complementary edge types on each panel. The panels should be identical and should arrange to form a coherent interlocking dodecahedron that self-corrects to the necessary 116.56 angle.

Comment: @HarishChandraRajpoot clarification above

Comment: @HarishChandraRajpoot There are three pentagons meeting at each vertex of a dodecahedron. Once you join those three pentagons together, the dihedral angles between each pair are rigidly fixed and will not change as you add the rest of the pentagons. It is unclear why you think you have to "join five pentagons simultaneously" to a sixth pentagon.

Comment: @ David: As you mentioned, by joining three pentagons together at a single vertex, you need to make four such smaller units each consisting of three pentagons & then further combine/unite them all either to form two larger units each consisting of six pentagons or simultaneously joining all four smaller units to form a dodecahedron. But as I mentioned, if you simultaneously join five pentagons at all five edges  of a sixth pentagon then you obtain two units, each consisting of six pentagons, which by joining together will generate a dodecahedron in minimum two steps.

Comment: Alternatively, a solid dodecahedron with edge length $a$ can also be manufactured from a solid sphere with a radius $\color{blue}{R=\frac{a\sqrt{3}(\sqrt{5}+1)}{4}}$ by performing facing operations on the sphere to generate 12 congruent regular pentagonal (flat) faces.

Answer (score 0):

Let $a$ be the edge length of each of 12 (regular) pentagonal panels. Then the inscribed radius $\color{blue}{r_{i}}$ of each pentagonal panel is $$\color{blue}{r_{i}}=\frac{a}{2}\cot \frac{\pi}{5}$$$$\color{blue}{=\frac{a}{2}\sqrt{\frac{5+2\sqrt{5}}{5}}}$$ 
in a dodecahedron, the radius $R_{i}$ of the inscribed spherical surface touching all 12 identical pentagons is given as $$\color{blue}{R_{i}=\frac{a}{2}\sqrt{\frac{25+11\sqrt{5}}{10}}}$$ Now assume that the dihedral angle between any two consecutive pentagonal faces (panels) meeting at the common edge is $\color{blue}{\theta}$ & drop a perpendicular to any of 12 pentagonal faces (panels) to obtain a right triangle in    which we have $$\tan\frac{\theta}{2}=\frac{R_{i}}{r_{i}}$$ $$=\frac{\frac{a}{2}\sqrt{\frac{25+11\sqrt{5}}{10}}}{\frac{a}{2}\sqrt{\frac{5+2\sqrt{5}}{5}}}$$ $$=\sqrt{\frac{25+11\sqrt{5}}{2(5+2\sqrt{5})}}=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$$  $$\implies\color{blue}{ \theta=2\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)\approx 116.5650512^o}$$

It is clear that each two pentagonal panels (faces), out of 12, are inclined with each other at an equal diahedral angle $\theta$ at the common edge.

Thus by mechanically joining (either by gluing or by welding) all 12 pentagonal panels at an equal angle $\theta\approx 116.5650512^o$ at all 30 edges each edge is shared (common) by two adjacent pentagonal panels (faces), the dodecahedron can be easily constructed/manufactured.

Comment: Exterior dihedral angle is simpler to remember  as $\tan^{-1}2$

Comment: @Narasimham That's good idea. Thanks